# 'ShutDown' or 'Reboot' linux system using MONO C#?

Tags: c#, mono

I'm developing an application to run on LINUX using MONO C#. I need to do shutdown and reboot the system on Linux. In windows we can do it easily by calling 'shutdown.exe' from Process.Start() method. I like to know how to do the same on Linux. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Why does an application ever need to reboot the system? It's not as if it's Microsoft Windows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways. Some possible commands you can invoke via `Process.Start()`:

- halt
- poweroff
- reboot
- shutdown

Have a look [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000606.htm) or several other websites or read the manuals of the commands for more information.

Take into account that your application/the user that runs it propably has not the necessary rights to reboot/shutdown the machine, and that the commands may not be in your `PATH`.